# Loading raster in postgis via raster2pgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, php, pgadmin-3

I need to import data file to my database.
I created a web interface in order to upload file
but I have already an error

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: rt_raster_from_wkb: wkb size
>   (0) < min size (61) LINE 1: INSERT INTO
>   eau_param_hydro(rast,filename) VALUES('','testte... ^ in
>   C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 32

My code is :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="fichier">Ajouter raster :</label><br />
     <input type="file" name="fichier"  />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" /> </form> 
       <?php $name = $_FILES['fichier']['name']; $db = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=gisdb user=postgres >password=******');           $output =shell_exec("raster2pgsql -a -s 32629 -I -C -F -M '".$_FILES["fichier"]["tmp_name"]."' eau_param_hydro | psql -U postgres -d gisdb -h localhost -p 5432 ");         $req = exec(" SELECT * FROM '".$output."' ");
    $result = pg_query($db,"INSERT INTO eau_param_hydro(rast,filename)  >VALUES('".$req."','".$name."');");
         if (!$result) { 
         $errormessage = pg_last_error(); 
         echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage; 
         exit(); 
        }  pg_close();  ?>
```

in PostGIS I have a table :

> CREATE TABLE eau_param_hydro (   rid serial NOT NULL,   rast raster,
>   filename text,   CONSTRAINT eau_param_hydro_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rid ),
>   CONSTRAINT enforce_num_bands_rast CHECK (st_numbands(rast) = 1),
>   CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_rast CHECK (st_srid(rast) = 4326) ) WITH (
>   OIDS=FALSE ); ALTER TABLE eau_param_hydro   OWNER TO postgres;
>
> -- Index: eau_param_hydro_st_convexhull_idx
>
> -- DROP INDEX eau_param_hydro_st_convexhull_idx;
>
> CREATE INDEX eau_param_hydro_st_convexhull_idx   ON eau_param_hydro
>   USING gist   (st_convexhull(rast) );

Comment: Why are you trying to insert with raster2pgsql as well as database insert? Your $req is no good.  The raster2pgsql is not going to return a raster, which it seems your code is assuming.  It will insert directly into the database assuming it even works.  Does that part work?

Comment: i need to insert a raster and the name of raster  to my data base postgres ( in table " eau_param_hydro ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with just PHP, not tested. 
Two useful links:
Writing binary files to postgres - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162695/store-blob-like-data-in-postgresql

-- this is a postgis function that converts a regular raster into a postgis raster
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_FromGDALRaster.html

You first of all need to do this with a parameterized query.  What you are doing will not work:

```
 <?php $fcontents = file_get_contents($_FILES["fichier"]["tmp_name"]);
   $db = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=gisdb user=postgres password=******');         
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO eau_param_hydro(filename,rast)
        VALUES($1, ST_FromGDALRaster( ($2)::bytea ) );';
   $params = array($_FILES["fichier"]["name"], pg_escape_bytea($fcontents) );

  $result = pg_query_params($db, $sql, $params);
  pg_close();  ?>
```

Comment: thanks , please what's $1 and $2 ?

Comment: That's how you parameterize in postgresql php.  with pg_query_params you provide an array of options (in this case $params).  The item in position 1, is what gets put in the query whereever you have $1 (so in this case the name you want to store.  $2 is the raster itself (since that is what I am putting in second element of $params array.

Comment: i have error : "  Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: function st_fromgdalraster(bytea) does not exist LINE 2: VALUES($1, ST_FromGDALRaster( ($2)::bytea ) ) ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. in C:\wamp\www\test\test.php on line 28 "

Comment: i need your help please

Comment: Which version of PostGIS are you running?  That function came in PostGIS 2.1.0, so if you are running an earlier PostGIS you wouldn't have it.  Lots of speed improvements for raster came in 2.1.0 so I would suggest upgrading if you can.

Comment: i upgrade teh version of postgis to 2.1.0 , but i have already a problem: ` Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERREUR: rt_util_gdal_open: Cannot open file. All GDAL drivers disabled in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 6 `

Comment: You need to enable drivers -- do  http://postgis.net/2015/05/02/tip_enable_raster_drivers/

Comment: Forgot to mention if you are on 9.5+ and 2.2+ you can use ALTER SYSTEM or ALTER DATABASE as listed here - http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html  otherwise for 2.1 and below have to define in env which varies by OS.

Comment: am in 9.1 and 2.2

Comment: You can't use ALTER SYSTEM, but you can still use ALTER DATABASE.  So try:  ALTER DATABASE your_database SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';  Then run your script after